# Wait until nested python script ends before continuing in current python script

Tags: python, module, system, subprocess

I have a python script that calls another python script. Inside the other python script it spawns some threads.How do I make the calling script wait until the called script is completely done running?

This is my code :

```
while(len(mProfiles) < num):
        print distro + " " + str(len(mProfiles))
        mod_scanProfiles.main(distro)
        time.sleep(180)
        mProfiles = readProfiles(mFile,num,distro)
        print "yoyo"
```

How do I wait until mod_scanProfiles.main() and all threads are completely finished? ( I used time.sleep(180) for now but its not good programming habit)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the `subprocess` module.  Can you show the code of `mod_scanProfiles.main(distro)`?

Comment: I am not using the subprocess module indeed... I was guessing I might need to use it to use it so i also tagged it

Comment: Two approaches: 1) use subprocess instead; 2) change `mod_scanProfiles.main()` to wait for all threads to finish before returning. Either way shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yeah, since you're not using `subprocess` you probably just need to do `Thread.join` to wait.

Comment: To wait for a thread to finish running, use the [.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to modify the code in `mod_scanProfiles.main` to block until all it's threads are finished.

Assuming you make a call to `subprocess.Popen` in that function just do:

```
# in mod_scanPfiles.main:
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
p.wait() # wait until the process completes.
```

If you're not currently waiting for your threads to end you'll also want to call `Thread.join` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)) to wait for them to complete.  For example:

```
# assuming you have a list of thread objects somewhere
threads = [MyThread(), ...]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. I used the join function on my thread list and it waits without using the subprocess now :)  thnx... didnt know it would be that simple...